# Angular 9 ngClass not working correctly in internet explorer 11

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular 9 app and I unfortunately need to support internet explorer.  I am trying to change css classes on a click event using ngClass and I have it working everywhere but internet explorer. I don't know if there are any polyfills I need to add to support ngClass or not.  A simple example of the issue is below.  I'm just changing a div's background color in this example and it works in chrome and firefox but not IE.

html example

```
<div (click)="toggle()" [ngClass]="active ? 'test' : 'test1'"></div>
```

typescript

```
 toggle(): void {
    if (this.active) {
      this.active = false;
    } else {
      this.active = true;
    }
  }
```

css

```
.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.test1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

When I click on the div the click triggers the method and the value changes but the css is never adjusted.

Comment: you create the bundles es2005 and es05?

Comment: @Eliseo I don't know what you mean, can you explain further please?

Comment: Do you have IE11 supported in your browserslist file?

Comment: In Angular you can generate bundles -the main.js,runtime.js,common.js..- in "es5" and in "es2015". For this, you need change the tsconfig.json indicate in compile options: 2015. https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration. In this case you generate both bundles. The "old" navigators use the "es5" bundles, the modern use the "es2015".

Comment: Oh I understand.  I had to switch my target to es5 just to get the project to run in internet explorer.  Would you suggest doing something else in addition to changing the target to es5?

Comment: @tlm this is what I have in my browserslist   
`> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11`

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a new `tsconfig-es5.app.json` file.

   {
   "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5"
   }
   }
2. Update `angular.json` configuration.

   "es5": {
   "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
   }
3. Run your application: `ng serve --configuration es5`. I recommend to
   add a run script in `package.json` for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think an if expression does work in `ngClass` try using something like this

```
<div (click)="toggle()" [ngClass]="{'test': active, 'test1': !active}"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same result.  Works fine in everything but IE